# How to use subversion in a hosting website?

Tags: svn, ftp

How can I work with Subversion, when I have a website that is on a free domain? How can I update my svn files when I change something in the website (It is a Wordpress website)?
Do I need to have a FTP Client to make this? Or there's another option? My website is hosted on Hostinger.

Answer (score 0):

Set up SVN server separately and work with SVN. Then deploy one version on the free server e.g. once a day.

Comment: There isn't a way to work simultaneously with both of them? Like it is in Eclipse or another IDE? So then I can just send to the SVN server the files I modified, and then send the information to the freehost?